# Extracting Geojson data from WFS to Leaflet

Tags: html, api, leaflet, gis, geojson

I am working on adding GeoJSON data from WFS features from :- https://emidius.mi.ingv.it/services/italy/wfs/?service=WFS&request=getCapabilities into the leaflet. However, I am not getting the GeoJSON data displayed in the map. Please do help me. I have skeleton of code below. Also,Please help to fix the error in code if any. The skeleton of the code is given below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Creating mash-ups with Leaflet</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://auth.airmap.com/js/keycloak.js"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #map {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 1000px;
    }
  </style>

  <head>

    <body>
      <div id="map"></div>
      <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([14.6361111, 42.1608333], 8);
        var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gebco_web_services/web_map_service/mapserv?', {
          layers: 'GEBCO_LATEST_SUB_ICE_TOPO'
        }).addTo(map);

        var elevation;

        $.getJSON('https://demo.pygeoapi.io/master/collections/ogr_gpkg_poi/items?f=json', function(value) {
          var datalayer = L.geoJson(value, {
            onEachFeature: function(feature, featureLayer) {
              var lon = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
              var lat = feature.geometry.coordinates[1];
              var city = feature.properties.name;

              $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.airmap.com/elevation/v1/ele/?points=' + lat + ',' + lon +
                  '&units=metric& appid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjcmVkZW50aWFsX2lkIjoiY3JlZGVudGlhbHxwQUFNWlBxaEx2T2Q2cGZSR2JkMlhDQkdRcTdNIiwiYXBwbGljYXRpb25faWQiOiJhcHBsaWNhdGlvbnx3ZURHZ01oTldtek55c1A4S0xEdlRsQW5QTE0iLCJvcmdhbml6YXRpb25faWQiOiJkZXZlbG9wZXJ8MnpvYmI3eWh4ZVk0cWtDM1BSeDBaSEtNejIzOCIsImlhdCI6MTQ3MTM3OTc0Mn0.MeO0jt6holPt0jdPJvRJrTBi380WsbOPGCEO6u-tfSo',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                  elevation = json.data;
                }
              });
              featureLayer.bindPopup("City: " + city + "</br>Elevation: " + elevation + "metres");
            }
          }).addTo(map);
  
      var wfs_url = 
      "https://emidius.mi.ingv.it/services/italy/wfs/?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=italy:CPTI_current&outputFormat=application/json&count=10&srsName=epsg:4326";

      $.getJSON(wfs_url).then((res) => {
        var layer = L.geoJson(res).addTo(map);

        map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
      });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The WFS service is returning `null` geometries. Contact the people responsible for the WFS service.